# Tomcat NIO connector creates threads on socket close

Tags: nio, tomcat8

I run Tomcat 8.0.20 with JDK 1.7.71 and when we load up the system with say a 1000 *Websocket* connections the number of threads is between 32-33 (nothing significantly more than what it started with when the app was loaded). But, when the test run stops, the sockets are closed and the threads increase to the max (200). These threads hang in there for about 60 seconds and then they die.

The server code is as follows: When a websocket is opened, an object of webSockHandler is instantiated. There is a routing class (static) that sends any incoming message to one of 4 managers. The 4 managers are each Runnable, and they are stuck in a take() of a LinkedBlockingQueue. These managers are common and there are no more threads created specifically to handle a client request. So, whether we have 0 load or a million, we should be at 4 application threads.

But, there is a clear 1:1 linkage on the NIO socket closure and a thread being created. The issue can be reproduced with Tomcat running on Win 7, 8 or Ubuntu - so its probably not the OS. Why are these threads being created when the client socket closes? Can we not avoid it? Or optimise it?

The rest of tomcat configurations are default (except the NIO connector. i.e. 2 threads, max Threads = 200, etc)

** Edit: Pasting some code snippets **
I wonder what part of the code should i send.. i'll try my best.

The *Managers are:

```
public void run() {
    while ( keepRunning ) {
      Message msgToProcess;
      try {
        msgToProcess = myQueue.take(); //myQueue is of type LinkedBlockingQueue
        processMessage(msgToProcess);
      } <<Exception blocks>>
    }
  }
```

The Websock handler is:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="location")
public class Websock {

    Websock(){
        log.info("Consutructor:Creating a new instance for every socket ");
    }

    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
        ConnectionManager.removeClient(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can understand that Tomcat creates a thread to handle 'work', but in this case, the socket close should have been dealt with instantly is it not? What  makes that work linger enough for Tomcat to create more and more threads to handle it? :(

Comment: Could you actually post your code example rather than describing it?

Comment: Sure, but I wonder what part of the code should i send.. i'll try my best. Here are the logical snippets     The * Managers are:  public void run() {
    while ( keepRunning ) {
      Message msgToProcess;
      try {
        msgToProcess = myQueue.take();
        processMessage(msgToProcess);
      } <<Exception blocks>>
    }
  }

Comment: I believe the problem may lie in our code - based on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878983/100-threads-timed-waiting-in-tomcat-causing-it-to-stall-as-total-number-of-thre    Will get back in a while

Comment: A socket close is not a message, and looking for bugs in Tomcat rather than in your own code is just displacement activity and a complete waste of time.