# Many threads are blocked and memory from old gen not releasing

Tags: multithreading, tomcat7, dump, thread-dump

I am using tomcat server and when i took thread dump i can see many threads are blocked (172) and other threads are IN_NATIVE (27). Almost many blocked  threads are like smiler to below. Can some one help what may be the reason. My 8GB OldGen space is full. After performing GC also its not releasing.

blocked threads :

```
    Thread 22614 - threadId:Thread 22614 - state:BLOCKED
stackTrace:
- java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
- java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) @bci=87, line=152 (Compiled frame)
- java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=11, line=122 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(boolean) @bci=59, line=512 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill() @bci=2, line=497 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper) @bci=263, line=203 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper, org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketStatus) @bci=96, line=515 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run() @bci=130, line=302 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1145 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
- java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)




Thread 23677 - threadId:Thread 23677 - state:BLOCKED
stackTrace:
- sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
- java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=226 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=68, line=2082 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=62, line=467 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=3, line=86 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=3, line=32 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=141, line=1068 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
- java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 23674 - threadId:Thread 23674 - state:BLOCKED
stackTrace:
- com.mysql.jdbc.SingleByteCharsetConverter.toString(byte[], int, int) @bci=1, line=322 (Compiled frame)
- com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getString(java.lang.String, com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection, byte[], int, int) @bci=54, line=797 (Compiled frame)
- com.mysql.jdbc.ByteArrayRow.getString(int, java.lang.String, com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection) @bci=24, line=72 (Compiled frame)
- com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(int, boolean) @bci=155, line=5699 (Compiled frame)
- com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(int) @bci=3, line=5576 (Compiled frame)
- com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(java.lang.String) @bci=6, line=5616 (Compiled frame)
- com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getString(java.lang.String) @bci=19, line=3342 (Compiled frame)
- org.hibernate.type.StringType.get(java.sql.ResultSet, java.lang.String) @bci=2, line=41 (Compiled frame)
- org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(java.sql.ResultSet, java.lang.String) @bci=3, line=184 (Compiled frame)
- org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(java.sql.ResultSet, java.lang.String, org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor, java.lang.Object) @bci=3, line=210 (Compiled frame)
```

Comment: Well, the thread dump doesn't seem to be accurate. `Unsafe.park` is a TIMED_WAITING, and socket.read is WAITING. Could you generate a thread dump via `kill -3 <tomcat_pid>`? It will include the address for the objects which are blocking threads, so you could check if there is a deadlock for example.

Answer (score 1):

- First stack trace indicates that thread tried to read from a socket and went into `BLOCKED` state. Socket read operation is a blocking operation which means that if there is nothing to read or till all the information is fully read, it will block.
- For second, `LinkedBlockingQueue.poll()` is a not a blocking operation so this is a normal stack trace to indicate usual idle thread. This is not caused by user code
- For third, that also doesn't look problematic as String value from result set is returned.

I think, you should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878983/100-threads-timed-waiting-in-tomcat-causing-it-to-stall-as-total-number-of-thre) too.

Stack trace # 1 and #3 might be related as that socket read might be DB read.

These stack traces will not help solve problem but these kind of blocked threads simply indicate a problem with too much memory and excessive garbage collection.

There might be a problem with your C3P0 pool or the way you might be creating statement and result set objects - all in all it seems a case of memory leak and resources not closing well.

Very precise answer is not possible without relevant application code. Also, as stated in comment, identity of lock object needs to be dumped too.

Hope it helps !!