# many Tomcat Threads sleeping - org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest

Tags: java, tomcat, thread-dump

While my tomcat server was up and working, it was not able to server requests from one specific app -  the browser would just keep spinning (just at the simple login page itself). No errors. From multiple thread dumps, i see only one this suspicious. There are 100's of the threads sleeping, all same stack trace.

Why would so all these be threads be sleeping at CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest ?

```
http-nio-8080-exec-159 - priority:6 - threadId:0x000000000f5f5000 - nativeId:0x658 - state:TIMED_WAITING
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
- locked <0x00000007dcc67fe8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [100 threads TIMED\_WAITING in tomcat, causing it to stall as total number of threads crosses 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878983/100-threads-timed-waiting-in-tomcat-causing-it-to-stall-as-total-number-of-thre)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the tomcat source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/3361b1321201431e65d59d168254cff4f8f8dc55/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/CoyoteAdapter.java#L761), the `postParseRequest` will sleep if the context is paused, [the context gets paused while it is being reloaded](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/8ec82f4b9080e219d1147fc65dc2bf2370a5b142/java/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardContext.java#L3680).

Looking through your thread dump to see which one is reloading the context, should shed some more light on the issue.

Comment: Thanks Magnus for pointing out. I was not able to find the evidence of application reload in Thread Dump, however i continued to dig the logs. There was a OOM when the app was getting reloaded. Below are logs.

Comment: INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/myrepoapp] has started
SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run Unexpected death of background thread ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError